# Как запустить Symfony 2.8 на обычном сервере LAMP

Tags: symfony

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос для тех людей которые хорошо знают Symfony 2.
Не один год работаю с php на фреймворках Codeigniter и Kohana.
Нужда заставляет разобраться в Symfony, и тут логика ломаеться, как можно запустить ее скачав и установить архива, так как это делаеться в вышеперечисленных фреймворках, а не через запуск php bin/console server:run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь, но дело обстоит так.
Пробовал все что написано на многих сайтах, в том числе на официальном Symfony.
Все это я пробовал на самой последней версии Centos 7. Она оказалась мягко говоря сыроватой. 
Но после смены системы на Ubuntu 16.04 все сразу заработало.

Answer (score 0):

На официальном сайте есть примеры файлов конфигурации для Apache и Nginx
https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Для Apache виртуальный хост может выглядет так:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld

DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
<Directory /var/www/project/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
# <Directory /var/www/project>
#     Options FollowSymlinks
# </Directory>

# optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
# which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
# not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
<Directory /var/www/project/web/bundles>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```